# Haskell - Using one data type kind in another

Tags: haskell, types

Haskell newbie; I want to be able to declare `Val` which can be either `IntVal, StringVal FloatVal` and a `List` which can be either `StringList, IntList, FloatList`, whose elements are (correspondingly): `StringVal, IntVal and FloatVal`.
My attempt so far:

```
data Val = IntVal Int
         | FloatVal Float
         | StringVal String deriving Show

data List = IntList [(IntVal Int)]
          | FloatList [(FloatVal Float)]
          | StringList [(StringVal String)] deriving Show
```

fails with the error:

```
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘IntVal’
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?

   data List = IntList [(IntVal Int)]

... (similarly for StringVal, FloatVal..)
```

what is the right way to achieve this?

PS:
declaring List as `data List = List [Val]` ends up allowing Lists as follows:
l = [(IntVal 10),(StringVal "Hello")], which I do not want to allow.

I want each element of list to be a `Value` of same kind

Comment: Define "fails". Examining the error message is part of the learning process.

Comment: `IntVal`/`FloatVal`/`StringVal` are not types!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a solution using GADTs.  The problem is that `IntVal` etc are not actually types, they are just constructors (basically functions that also support pattern matching) for the single type `Val`. So once you have made a `Val`, the information about which kind of value it is is completely lost at the type level (that is, compile time).

The trick is to tag `Val` with the type it contains.

```
data Val a where
    IntVal :: Int -> Val Int
    FloatVal :: Float -> Val Float
    StringVal :: String -> Val String
```

Then if you have a plain list `[Val a]` it will already be homogeneous.  If you must:

```
data List = IntList [Val Int]
          | FloatList [Val Float]
          ...
```

which is slightly different in that it "erases" the type of list, and it can distinguish between an empty list of ints and an empty list of floats, for example.  You could also use the same GADT trick with List

```
data List a where
    IntList :: [Val Int] -> List Int
    FloatList :: [Val Float] -> List Float
    ...
```

but in that case I think a better design is probably the simpler

```
newtype List a = List [Val a]
```

The trade-offs between all these different designs really depends on what you are planning to do with them.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using GADTs? probably a compromise solution

Comment: @Ngm Sure: `data List = IntList [Int] | FloatList [Float] | StringList [String]`.

Comment: If you don't mind being a little more polymorphic, there's `data Val a = Val a`, in which case `IntVal`, `FloatVal`, etc. are all just spelled `Val`.  But that doesn't prevent having a `Val Bool`, or `Val [(String -> Double, IO ())]`, or whatever.  If you want the element type to be reflected in the choice of constructor, chosen from a finite set of choices as in your question, then GADTs are the feature that does that.

Comment: @DanielWagner I did try that, the problem then is that is not really a List of Vals and you need a way to translate into Vals, but yes its a good compromise solution